# CUDA installation gone wrong on a fresh Ubuntu installation (dependency problems)

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I'm sorry it's come to this. I normally don't like to just dump such a specific problem onto here. But I've been at this for many hours.

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 with minimal applications but enabling 3rd party drivers. I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 which I want to use for deep learning purposes. The driver version is 460.

Now when I follow the instructions here to install the CUDA version I need, I get the output at the end of this post on the last step (I removed the lines for "Get: N", "preparing to unpack" and "unpacking" to stay within the character limit for this post).

I've seen plenty of CUDA installation forum questions online but none having the same issues I am so I'm just at a loss. Does anyone know why I'm getting these errors?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386
  libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386 libfprint-2-tod1 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libllvm10 libllvm11:i386 libnvidia-common-460
  libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libvulkan1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java cuda-11-0 cuda-command-line-tools-11-0
  cuda-compiler-11-0 cuda-cudart-11-0 cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 cuda-cuobjdump-11-0
  cuda-cupti-11-0 cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
  cuda-documentation-11-0 cuda-driver-dev-11-0 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-450
  cuda-gdb-11-0 cuda-libraries-11-0 cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 cuda-memcheck-11-0
  cuda-nsight-11-0 cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 cuda-nsight-systems-11-0
  cuda-nvcc-11-0 cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 cuda-nvprof-11-0
  cuda-nvprune-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 cuda-nvtx-11-0
  cuda-nvvp-11-0 cuda-runtime-11-0 cuda-samples-11-0 cuda-sanitizer-11-0
  cuda-toolkit-11-0 cuda-tools-11-0 cuda-visual-tools-11-0 default-jre
  default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra freeglut3 freeglut3-dev java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libcublas-11-0
  libcublas-dev-11-0 libcufft-11-0 libcufft-dev-11-0 libcurand-11-0
  libcurand-dev-11-0 libcusolver-11-0 libcusolver-dev-11-0 libcusparse-11-0
  libcusparse-dev-11-0 libegl-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev
  libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libice-dev libnpp-11-0
  libnpp-dev-11-0 libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-common-450
  libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-encode-450
  libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450
  libnvjpeg-11-0 libnvjpeg-dev-11-0 libopengl-dev libopengl0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
  libxt-dev nsight-compute-2020.1.1 nsight-systems-2020.3.2
  nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-driver-450
  nvidia-kernel-common-450 nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-modprobe
  nvidia-utils-450 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-xext-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450 xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  libice-doc libsm-doc libx11-doc libxcb-doc libxext-doc libxt-doc
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  | fonts-wqy-zenhei
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-450:i386 libnvidia-decode-450:i386
  libnvidia-encode-450:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386
  libnvidia-gl-450:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libnvidia-cfg1-460 libnvidia-compute-460 libnvidia-compute-460:i386
  libnvidia-decode-460 libnvidia-decode-460:i386 libnvidia-encode-460
  libnvidia-encode-460:i386 libnvidia-extra-460 libnvidia-fbc1-460
  libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 libnvidia-gl-460 libnvidia-gl-460:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-460 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386
  linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge nvidia-compute-utils-460
  nvidia-dkms-460 nvidia-driver-460 nvidia-kernel-common-460
  nvidia-kernel-source-460 nvidia-utils-460 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460
The following NEW packages will be installed
  ca-certificates-java cuda cuda-11-0 cuda-command-line-tools-11-0
  cuda-compiler-11-0 cuda-cudart-11-0 cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 cuda-cuobjdump-11-0
  cuda-cupti-11-0 cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
  cuda-documentation-11-0 cuda-driver-dev-11-0 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-450
  cuda-gdb-11-0 cuda-libraries-11-0 cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 cuda-memcheck-11-0
  cuda-nsight-11-0 cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 cuda-nsight-systems-11-0
  cuda-nvcc-11-0 cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 cuda-nvprof-11-0
  cuda-nvprune-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 cuda-nvtx-11-0
  cuda-nvvp-11-0 cuda-runtime-11-0 cuda-samples-11-0 cuda-sanitizer-11-0
  cuda-toolkit-11-0 cuda-tools-11-0 cuda-visual-tools-11-0 default-jre
  default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra freeglut3 freeglut3-dev java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libcublas-11-0
  libcublas-dev-11-0 libcufft-11-0 libcufft-dev-11-0 libcurand-11-0
  libcurand-dev-11-0 libcusolver-11-0 libcusolver-dev-11-0 libcusparse-11-0
  libcusparse-dev-11-0 libegl-dev libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev
  libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libice-dev libnpp-11-0
  libnpp-dev-11-0 libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-common-450
  libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-encode-450
  libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450
  libnvjpeg-11-0 libnvjpeg-dev-11-0 libopengl-dev libopengl0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers
  libxt-dev nsight-compute-2020.1.1 nsight-systems-2020.3.2
  nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-driver-450
  nvidia-kernel-common-450 nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-modprobe
  nvidia-utils-450 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-xext-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450 xtrans-dev
0 to upgrade, 109 to newly install, 22 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
Need to get 42.4 MB/2,276 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,663 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Fetched 42.4 MB in 10s (4,272 kB/s)                                            
Extract templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 168274 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-driver-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-encode-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-decode-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-utils-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-extra-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-gl-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge (5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-compute-utils-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-dkms-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '': No such file or directory
Done.
INFO:Disable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-kernel-common-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-kernel-source-460 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libnvidia-compute-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package java-common.
(Reading database ... 167626 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../000-java-common_0.72_all.deb ...
Unpacking java-common (0.72) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64.
Setting up libcurand-11-0 (10.2.1.218-1) ...
Setting up libcublas-11-0 (11.1.0.229-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvtx-11-0 (11.0.167-1) ...
Setting up freeglut3:amd64 (2.8.1-3) ...
Setting up nsight-systems-2020.3.2 (2020.3.2.6-87e152c) ...
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2020.3.2/target-linux-x64/nsys to provide /usr/local/bin/nsys (nsys) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2020.3.2/host-linux-x64/nsight-sys to provide /usr/local/bin/nsight-sys (nsight-sys) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2020.3.2/host-linux-x64/nsys-ui to provide /usr/local/bin/nsys-ui (nsys-ui) in auto mode
Setting up java-common (0.72) ...
Setting up libcusolver-11-0 (10.5.0.218-1) ...
Setting up cuda-driver-dev-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-common-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-memcheck-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.4-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvprune-11-0 (11.0.167-1) ...
Setting up libopengl0:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvjpeg-11-0 (11.1.0.218-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cudart-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-modprobe (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xtrans-dev (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvprof-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 (11.0.167-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgles1:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libcusparse-11-0 (11.1.0.218-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 126) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 133) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 126) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nvidia-persistenced.service → /lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service.
Setting up cuda-cuobjdump-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libcufft-11-0 (10.2.0.218-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvrtc-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up cuda-sanitizer-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-extra-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fonts-dejavu-extra (2.37-1) ...
Setting up libcufft-dev-11-0 (10.2.0.218-1) ...
Setting up libnpp-11-0 (11.1.0.218-1) ...
Setting up libcusolver-dev-11-0 (10.5.0.218-1) ...
Setting up xorg-sgml-doctools (1:1.11-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java (0.37.1-1) ...
Setting up libopengl-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up nsight-compute-2020.1.1 (2020.1.1.8-1) ...
Setting up libcublas-dev-11-0 (11.1.0.229-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcusparse-dev-11-0 (11.1.0.218-1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up cuda-nsight-systems-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
Setting up libcurand-dev-11-0 (10.2.1.218-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau
from loading. This can be reverted by deleting the following file:
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf

A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please regenerate your
initrd by running the following command after deleting the modprobe.d file:
`/usr/sbin/initramfs -u`

*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***
*** be loaded.                                                            ***
*****************************************************************************

INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-450.51.05 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-48-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-48-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.51.05/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-450 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-450 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-450:
 nvidia-driver-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (= 450.51.05-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-450 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                             Setting up libnpp-dev-11-0 (11.1.0.218-1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
Setting up cuda-gdb-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
Setting up libnvjpeg-dev-11-0 (11.1.0.218-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-nvcc-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64 (0.37.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-450:
 cuda-drivers-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.
 cuda-drivers-450 depends on nvidia-driver-450 (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package nvidia-driver-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-450 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                             Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-450:amd64 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-cupti-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up cuda-compiler-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-450 (= 450.51.05-1); however:
  Package cuda-drivers-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Setting up cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-11-0:
 cuda-runtime-11-0 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                  No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
       dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-11-0:
 cuda-11-0 depends on cuda-runtime-11-0 (>= 11.0.2); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-11-0:
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0 depends on cuda-runtime-11-0; however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
 cuda depends on cuda-11-0 (>= 11.0.2); however:
  Package cuda-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Setting up default-jre-headless (2:1.11-72) ...
Setting up openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jfr to provide /usr/bin/jfr (jfr) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
Setting up openjdk-11-jre:amd64 (11.0.10+9-0ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up default-jre (2:1.11-72) ...
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20190405ubuntu1) ...
head: cannot open '/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts' for reading: No such file or directory
Adding debian:UCA_Global_G2_Root.pem
Adding debian:IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.pem
Adding debian:AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R1.pem
Adding debian:XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
Adding debian:Certigna_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R4.pem
Adding debian:Secure_Global_CA.pem
Adding debian:UCA_Extended_Validation_Root.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R6.pem
Adding debian:Trustwave_Global_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
Adding debian:USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.pem
Adding debian:ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
Adding debian:DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
Adding debian:TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:Certigna.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:e-Szigno_Root_CA_2017.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
Adding debian:Trustwave_Global_ECC_P384_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:emSign_Root_CA_-_C1.pem
Adding debian:Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem
Adding debian:NAVER_Global_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
Adding debian:Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Microsoft_ECC_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R3.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA.pem
Adding debian:emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_C3.pem
Adding debian:certSIGN_Root_CA_G2.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Adding debian:CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
Adding debian:Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem
Adding debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-2.pem
Adding debian:Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
Adding debian:CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
Adding debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
Adding debian:SecureTrust_CA.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
Adding debian:Trustwave_Global_ECC_P256_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.pem
Adding debian:Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:EC-ACC.pem
Adding debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem
Adding debian:Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
Adding debian:GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
Adding debian:USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:GTS_Root_R2.pem
Adding debian:Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
Adding debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA_R2.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:Izenpe.com.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GC_CA.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_ECA-1.pem
Adding debian:ISRG_Root_X1.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
Adding debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-1.pem
Adding debian:SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
Adding debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem
Adding debian:Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
Adding debian:ACCVRAIZ1.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem
Adding debian:emSign_Root_CA_-_G1.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Microsoft_RSA_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
done.
Setting up cuda-nvvp-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nsight-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up cuda-visual-tools-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
Setting up cuda-tools-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.29.1) ...
Setting up x11proto-dev (2019.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxau-dev:amd64 (1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-48-generic
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Setting up libice-dev:amd64 (2:1.0.10-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsm-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
Setting up libxdmcp-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up x11proto-core-dev (2019.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up x11proto-input-dev (2019.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up x11proto-xext-dev (2019.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxcb1-dev:amd64 (1.14-2) ...
Setting up libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libxfixes-dev:amd64 (1:5.0.3-2) ...
Setting up libxt-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.5-1) ...
Setting up libxext-dev:amd64 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libglx-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libxi-dev:amd64 (2:1.7.10-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgl-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libxmu-headers (2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libegl-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libxmu-dev:amd64 (2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 (9.0.1-1build1) ...
Setting up libgles-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libglvnd-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up freeglut3-dev:amd64 (2.8.1-3) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up cuda-samples-11-0 (11.0.194-1) ...
Setting up cuda-documentation-11-0 (11.0.207-1) ...
Setting up cuda-toolkit-11-0 (11.0.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-450
 nvidia-driver-450
 cuda-drivers-450
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-11-0
 cuda-11-0
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What command did you use to start the install ?

Comment: @Saxtheowl I used `sudo apt-get -y install cuda`

Comment: I think I'm onto something (for the 500th time). I have nvidia driver 460. Should I first uninstall that, and install 450? Are the cuda versions coupled to the driver versions?

Comment: This seem like a good test yes

Comment: Since "cuda" is not a package in the standard repos, I assume you are using a PPA -- which one?  There are good answers on this site for installing cuda via the Nvidia .run file or the Nvidia deb file, which slice out the Nvidia driver dependencies,  I suggest you set up the latest Nvidia driverr (460) and use one of those installation methods.  If you manage to get cuda installed, depending upon the driver, you are in for a world of hurt when the driver updates or a new kernel is installed.

Comment: @ubfan1 I ended up using [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-gpu-installation-on-ubuntu-18-4-9b12230a1d31) which has some mistakes but combined with official docs I made it work. I'm now permanently traumatised after this ordeal, so your warning is scaring me. I used the ppa on that link. Does that mean I'm not in for that world of hurt?

Comment: I have no direct experience with the PPA method, since it never offered me the exact versions I needed.  But your dependency problems are basically the same as the ones with the other installation methods.  See other questions here relating to the problems with updates for cuda setups tied to some non-system supplied Nvidia driver.  Figure out if it's worth it to you to do more work now to avoid future update issues. My feeling is that CUDA is just an app, and should not dictate system drivers. Downside is no CUDA updates (some consider that good).